# Como colocar dois registros de uma tabela em outra como um só no select Banco MySql

Tags: mysql, sql

Como colocar dois registros de uma tabela em outra como um só no select Banco MySql?

```
SELECT TURMA.turma_id, TURMA.turma_nome, PROF.prof_name 
from turma TURMA LEFT JOIN professor_materia PROF_MAT 
ON TURMA.turma_id=PROF_MAT.prom_mat LEFT JOIN professor PROF 
ON PROF_MAT.prom_prof=PROF.prof_id
```

ele está retornando assim:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria que retorna-se Assim:

```
turma_id   |  turma_nome     |  prof_name
1          |  1º ANO A       |  PROFESSOR DE MATEMATICA, DANIEL
2          |  2º ANO         |  NULL
```

Desde já agradeço.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neste caso basta usar um `GROUP BY` com a função `GROUP_CONCAT`, ex:

```
SELECT
    MIN(TURMA.turma_id) AS turma_id,
    TURMA.turma_nome,
    GROUP_CONCAT(PROF.prof_name SEPARATOR ', ') AS prof_name
FROM
    turma TURMA
    LEFT JOIN professor_materia PROF_MAT ON TURMA.turma_id = PROF_MAT.prom_mat
    LEFT JOIN professor PROF ON PROF_MAT.prom_prof=PROF.prof_id
GROUP BY
    TURMA.turma_nome
```

O `GROUP BY` agrupa o resultado e o `GROUP_CONCAT` concatena os resultados agrupados de uma coluna.

Para ler mais sobre `GROUP BY` e `GROUP_CONCAT`: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat